# How to create a looping random number generator

Tags: php

I need to create a looping random number generator so each loops pumps out a different set of random numbers.

e.g result would be:

```
9463216549
6541335466
6749746326
6546879994
```

Code I have so far is:

```
<?php
$limit1 = 10;
$counter1 = 1;
$limit2 = 4;
$counter2 = 1;

while ($counter2 <= $limit2) {
    while ($counter1 <= $limit1) {
        $rayndom = mt_rand(0,6);
        $counter1++;    
    }
    $counter2++;
}
?>
```

Comment: what results are you getting *now?* You didn't say what isn't working the way you'd like it to.

Comment: At the moment I am getting one row of random numbers. I essentially need the mt_rand to 'reset' each loop, and give me 4 sets of random numbers.

Comment: Does "pumps out" mean print? Or do you want to store the results in a variable? The fundamental issue currently is that you re-assign that same `$rayndom` variable each loop (and thus only receive the last assignment).

Comment: The numbers are being used elsewhere in a code, so if you can imagine on the first loop, the integers 0-6 relate to one wave of monsters, but I need the next wave to release a different wave with a different sequence of monsters that are related to the numbers 0-6.

e.g.
Wave 1 = 0 2 3 5 6 1
Wave 2 = 4 3 5 4 6
etc.

But it can't be a random whole number such as random_int(), because it is a different monster each time relating to a single number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code hope this helps

```
<?php
$waves = array(
         array(),
         array(),
         array(),
         array()
         );

  foreach($waves as $wave) {
    for($counter = 1; $counter <= 10; $counter++) {
      $num = mt_rand(0,6);
      array_push($wave, $num);
    }
    print_r($wave);
  }
?>
```

Your array will look like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 6
    [8] => 5
    [9] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 4
    [9] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 3
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 3
    [8] => 5
    [9] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 4
    [7] => 4
    [8] => 4
    [9] => 6
)
```

each array will be one wave

Comment: Hey, that works, but my code needs to be individual integers, on the inner loop.
Loop 1:
2, then 3, then 6, then 9 etc.
Loop 2:
9, then 8, then 4, then 6 etc.
etc.

Comment: if it works 100% it would be good if you could up vote my work people have been copying my work and getting all of the votes

Comment: Hey, this is not what I'm looking for. You have just separated a single loop into chunks of ten numbers 4 times, not performed 4 separate loops.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `php version > 7` you can use inbuilt function [random_int()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php):

> Generates cryptographically secure pseudo-random integers

Usage of `random_int()`:

```
random_int(0, 1000); // 0 is min value and 1000 is max
```

`random_int()` is always safe alternative to `rand()` and `mt_rand()`

If you are using `PHP version < 7.0` then you can take a look at userland implementation of `random_int` i.e. [`random_compat`](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat).